# How to change column formats during csv import

Tags: excel, csv, import, vba

I import a .csv file via

```
Sub Datei_Importieren()
  Dim strFileName As String, arrDaten, arrTmp, lngR As Long, lngLast As Long
  Const cstrDelim As String = VBA.Constants.vbTab 'Trennzeichen

  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Datei wählen"
    .InitialFileName = "C:\Test\*.csv"  'Pfad anpassen
    .Filters.Add "CSV-Dateien", "*.csv", 1
    If .Show = -1 Then
      strFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
  End With

  If strFileName <> "" Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Open strFileName For Input As #1
    arrDaten = Split(Input(LOF(1), 1), vbCrLf)
    Close #1
    For lngR = 1 To UBound(arrDaten)
      arrTmp = Split(arrDaten(lngR), cstrDelim)
      If UBound(arrTmp) > -1 Then
        With ActiveSheet
          lngLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
          lngLast = Application.Max(lngLast, 10)
          .Cells(lngLast, 1).Resize(, UBound(arrTmp) + 1) _
            = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(arrTmp))
        End With
      End If
    Next lngR
  End If
End Sub
```

The functionality works perfect but I want to set column D to text but just cannot find the argument. Anyone who can help me here?

Comment: `.Range("D1:D" & lngLast).NumberFormat  = "@"`

Comment: do you always want it to display 3 digits? If so, use `="000"`

Comment: try `="###"` or `="##0"`

Comment: I just remembered you can import as CSV via vba the same way you do manually. That is probably better way to go because you can define the datatypes directly in that. A simple way to get it would be to record a macro of yourself doing it manually (then make adjustments as needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me

```
Sub Import_Zeros()

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\test\export.xls" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "export"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 936
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("D19").Select
    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
End Sub
```

You can adjust the format here: `Array(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1)`